# module posixpath has no attribute 'json'

Tags: python-3.x

````
```
def get_data():
    cache = os.path.join(directory, 'results')
    if os.path.exists(cache):
    print('loading from cache')
    with open(cache, "r") as f:
        return json.load(f)

```
````

I am trying to load the data from the cache in json format and read it

Comment: Did you use `import json` at the start of your program?

Comment: yes i did and imported os as well

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the issue, the easy solution to this is to add a `\` at the end of `directory` variable if you have not added.

I was using `os.getcwd()` function which return current working directory ex: `/home/dummy/repo/project` but it does not have last slash and hence I was facing the issue.
After concatenating slash at the end solved my issue.